# ADODB string connection fo SharePoint list via VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint, adodb

With connection string like this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
"DATABASE=" & sSHAREPOINT_SITE & ";" & _
"LIST=" & sDEMAND_ROLE_GUID & ";"
```

on Windows 7 computer with Excel 2007 ADODB connection is opened without any problem but when I try this code on Windows 10 computer I receive error (Invalid argument).

When I changed connection strong to this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
"DATABASE=" & sSHAREPOINT_SITE & ";" & _
"LIST=" & sDEMAND_ROLE_GUID & ";"
```

I also receive error (Invalid argument). My question is there any difference when I use different operation systems and I try to connect to SharePoint by the same code?

What connection string should I use to open connection with SharePoint on Windows 10 using Excel 2016?

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Is Access part of the Office installation? With office version is installed (32/64bit?)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know is the ACE.OLEDB.16.0 the newest driver. For further examples of connectionstrings look [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sharepoint/). But I think your problem is based on mixing 32-bit and 64-bit applications/driver.